# i get error error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback' when make search

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, c#-7.0

I work on the blazer web app .NET core 7 Server Side. I face an error.

```
error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback'
```

How can I solve this error?

I try clicking button to search for data but I get the error cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback'

```
Dashboar.Razor
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="display: flex;direction: ltr;" @onclick="Search">
<span class="bi bi-plus-circle" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span>Filter
</button>
```

DashboarBase.cs

```
public List<ApplicationDto> Search()
{
    isLoading = true;
    
    ApplicationsFilterDto obj = new ApplicationsFilterDto();
    obj.serverID = serverID;
    obj.ownerId = ownerId;
    obj.databaseId = databaseId;
    isLoading = false;
    AllApplicationsList = _EmplyeeService.ListOfApplications(obj);
    return AllApplicationsList;
}
```

service

```
IEmployeeService 

List<ApplicationDto> ListOfApplications(ApplicationsFilterDto obj);

EmployeeService
```

function return ApplicationDto

```
public List<ApplicationDto> ListOfApplications(ApplicationsFilterDto emp)
{
    var appList = _context.Database.SqlQuery<ApplicationDto>($"select ApplicationsData.ApplicationID as ApplicationId,Application_Name as ApplicationName,CommonName,d.DetailsName as TypeOfApplication,AccessType,d.DetailsName Criticality,o.OwnerName as ApplicationOwner,DRRequired,se.[DB_Name] as [DataBase] from ApplicationsData left join [dbo].[Details] d with(nolock) on d.ID=ApplicationsData.ApplicationType and d.HeaderId=6 left join [dbo].[Details] d2 with(nolock) on d2.ID=ApplicationsData.Criticality and d2.HeaderId=7\r\nleft join dbo.[Owner] o with(nolock) on o.ApplicationId=ApplicationsData.ApplicationID\r\nleft join dbo.[DataBase] se with(nolock) on se.ServerID=ApplicationsData.ServerId where ApplicationsData.ServerId={emp.serverID} OR SE.[DBID]={emp.databaseId} OR o.OwnerId={emp.ownerId}").ToList(); 
    
    return  appList;  
}
```

filter model

```
public class EmployeeFilterDto
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

return model

```
public class ApplicationDto
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public string CommonName { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfApplication { get; set; }
    public string AccessType { get; set; }
    public string Criticality { get; set; }
    public string DataBase { get; set; }
    public string BSSVServer { get; set; }
    public string DRRequired { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationOwner { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please could you edit your post for format your code? The indentation is all over the place at the moment, making it *really* hard to read.

Comment: i modified code indentatio

Comment: try changing your `public  List<ApplicationDto> Search()` to `public  async Task Search()` and don't return the list from the button handler

Comment: Is that *really* how your code looks in VS or whatever IDE you're using, with all opening braces indented four spaces relative to the class declaration? (And even worse for method declarations?) That seems unlikely to me. (And I really don't understand what the three lines under "service" are meant to tell us...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the event arguments and have incorrect return type. The following should work:

```cs
public void Search(MouseEventArgs e)
{
  // ...
}
```